# FCM Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I am using 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0' but some devices with android 8 are presenting this error java.lang.IllegalStateException Not allowed to start service Intent. After research I did not found something clear about how to fix this.

Code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagesService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


public static final String FCM_ACTION_MESSAGE = "com.project.services.fcm.ACTION_MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "VALUE";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Log.d("FCM", gson.toJson(remoteMessage.getData()));
    FirebaseMessage message = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(remoteMessage.getData()), FirebaseMessage.class);
    Intent intent = new Intent(FCM_ACTION_MESSAGE);
    intent.setPackage("com.project");
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Any idea how to avoid this IllegalStateException on android 8 using FCM?

Comment: Oreo [limits background execution](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html).

Comment: use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService` and promote your service to a foreground service.

Comment: @MarkKeen what exactly do you mean ? do you have some code of example with the solution? do you mean startForegroundService(intent); ?

Comment: I`m quoting the method, not how to implement it. Its part of v4 support library - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html - use it or don't, either way you'll have to handle Oreo background restrictions to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from android O, you cannot start a IntentService in background. You need to create background service for it.

Instead of this you need to do following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    startForegroundService(intent)
} else {
    startService(intent);
}
```

In `onHandleIntent` do following:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM Notif");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Processing notification..");
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
        startForeground(100, mBuilder.mNotification);
    }
```

Comment: Done, also @Sagar help me with a vote in the post thanks